# Disable DrawerNavigator Swipe Gesture at inner Stack/Tab in React Navigation v5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-drawer

I am using react-navigation v5 and have the navigation arranged like this -

```
<DrawerNavigator>
    <TabNavigator>
         <StackNavigator/> 
    </TabNavigator>
</DrawerNavigator>
```

I want to disable Drawer swipe action in one Tab/Stack. In earlier versions, it was achieved through `drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed'`, option but its not there in v5. There is option called `swipeEnabled` in DrawerNavigator option and I couldnt use it inside stack/tab navigator. How to achieve this feature in v5?